# Replacement of element in a list of python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am quite new with python and I try to replace the elements of a list with x given the specific list has the same elements. For example:

```
list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a = [1,4,7,9]
```

The list should become like:

```
list =[x,2,3,x,5,6,x,8,x]
```

Comment: try `list = ["x" if i in a else i for i in list]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rebuild your list using list comprehension, and a ternary to decide whether keep the original element or the replacement:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a = {1,4,7,9}

result = ["x" if i in a else i for i in lst]
```

which yields:

```
['x', 2, 3, 'x', 5, 6, 'x', 8, 'x']
```

note that it's better if `a` is a `set` in the general case, where there's a lot of elements, so the lookup is faster than on a `list`.

notes:

- don't use `list` as a variable name as it shadows the `list` type. I used `lst` as you noticed
- this method creates another `list`, if you want to modify `lst`, assign to `lst` instead of `result` (a classical loop is also possible instead of the comprehension)

Comment: Don't use `l` as a variable name either, as it looks too much like `1`.

Comment: python downvote police. The people who don't like python questions without attempts to be answered, even if they're okay. They downvote the question & the answer(s). I heard there's a chatroom for this (you'll never see me there...)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop within a while loop to do this.

```
counter = 0
while counter < len(list):
    for x in a:
        if list[counter] == x:
            list[counter] = "x"
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Why use a `while` loop? And why loop over a? Just check `if element in a`...  it's looping over `a` but not in Python.